# Imports in and iOS Today Extension not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, import, ios8-today-widget

I'm trying to import some libraries into a today extension (working fine in the main app). When I run the app, I get the errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Budget", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TodayViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_JBBarChartView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TodayViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Users", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TodayViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here are the imports:

```
#import "JBBarChartView.h"
#import "JBChartView.h"
#import "Users.h"
#import "Budget.h"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Select the file and in the file inspector, set the target to your todays extension's target to make the file available to the target.

Comment: @insane-36 the target membership area is greyed out. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: Ignore me. .m files... not the implementation files.

Comment: OKay, so I've sorted the target memberships out, but now I've received over 20+ 'parse errors' with files that were working fine before.

Comment: Ok, if you have parsing error, that means there is some error. Resolve the error.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this? I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: Yes. With the imports you want to use, click on the files (i.e Users.h) and check the target membership in the right hand question mark column, and make sure all the targets are selected. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use pods and import some libraries,you can edit Podfile like this:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.1'

  # Has its own copy of OCMock
  # and has access to GoogleAnalytics via the app
  # that hosts the today target

  target 'MyAppToday' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'OCMock', '~> 2.0.1'
  end
end
```

If you want use your own class,click this file and check the target membership.You also can pack these file as a framework.